# Wrong calculation in Sum()

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sum, sql-query-store

hi i have 2 table and i want plus it.

```
Table 1 --> StudentId = 1 ,Score = 10 , 20 ,30  , StudentId = 2 ,Score = 5, 5
Table 2 --> StudentId = 1 ,Score = 5, 10 ,15    , StudentId = 2 ,Score = 15, 25
Total = StudentId = 1 ---> 90  , StudentId = 2 ---> 45
```

i use this query:

```
Select Sum(tbl_EvaPoint.Score + tbl_ActPoint.Score ), 
       tbl_ActPoint.StudentId 
From tbl_EvaPoint 
JOIN tbl_ActPoint 
  ON tbl_EvaPoint.StudentId = tbl_ActPoint.StudentId 
GROUP BY tbl_ActPoint.StudentId`
```

everythings is ok but i get wrong sum instead of 90 and 45 i get 180 and 90 or somthings else.

Comment: Can you use a table format to show the data. Like [**THIS**](https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/) or show us what is the db schema, not sure what is that structure. But by guess is you need `UNION` not `JOIN`

Comment: Can you provide input table structure and expected output?

Comment: Don't put "Solved" in the questions title. **Accept** the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNION` instead of `JOIN`

```
SELECT student_id, SUM(score)
FROM (SELECT student_id, score FROM Table1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT student_id, score FROM Table2
     ) as T
GROUP BY  student_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a CTE is more readable, but that is personal preference.

```
CREATE TABLE #S1 (
     StudentID smallint
    ,Score smallint )

INSERT INTO #S1
SELECT 1, 10;
INSERT INTO #S1
SELECT 1, 20;
INSERT INTO #S1
SELECT 1, 30;
INSERT INTO #S1
SELECT 2, 5
INSERT INTO #S1
SELECT 2, 5;

CREATE TABLE #S2 (
     StudentID smallint
    ,Score smallint )

INSERT INTO #S2
SELECT 1, 5;
INSERT INTO #S2
SELECT 1, 10;
INSERT INTO #S2
SELECT 1, 15;
INSERT INTO #S2
SELECT 2, 15;
INSERT INTO #S2
SELECT 2, 25;

WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 
    StudentID, Score
FROM #S1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
    StudentID, Score
FROM #S2 )

SELECT 
     StudentID
    ,SUM(Score) AS TotalScore
FROM CTE
GROUP BY StudentID
```